# How to add the possibility to activate/deactivate my application customiser-SPFX

Tags: spfx, feature-stapling, spfx-extensions

From this article [Use an SPFx Application Customizer to add JavaScript (e.g. header) to every page in a site](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html)

I can see you can enable a feature does one disable the feature.
Not tried it yet but will this also actually remove the extension?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Tried it and it worked

Comment: Can you please explain how?